# Regex - removing sub-words

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have an array of strings as so:

```
var people = ['FirstName.Bob.Boy', 'FirstName.James.Boy', 'FirstName.Obama.Boy']
```

Essentially my goal is strip of `FirstName` and `Boy` to have the new array as so:

```
var people = ['Bob', 'James', 'Obama']
```

What would be the most straightforward approach? Using Regex?

Comment: shouldn't the last one be Obama ?

Comment: What is the rule for extracting names? Will `FirstName` and `Boy` always be present, in exactly that form? Do you want to extract the middle of three dot-delimited substrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use native js [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function

```js
var people = ['FirstName.Bob.Boy', 'FirstName.James.Boy', 'FirstName.Obama.Boy'];

var result = people.map(function(name){return name.split(".")[1]});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to string, replace everything that you want and parse it back to javascript array. That's one possible solution

```js
var people = ['FirstName.Bob.Boy', 'FirstName.James.Boy', 'FirstName.Obama.Boy'];

people = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people)
            .replace(new RegExp('FirstName\.([^\.]*)\.Boy', 'g'), '$1'));

console.log(people);
```